# Нужно, чтобы я писал цифру прописью "два", а мне выводилось число "2"

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, словари

У меня проблема с циклом: не могу написать алгоритм, чтобы он проверял это слово с индексом первого списка, и по индексу первого списка, выдавал из второго:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as mb

def __init__():
    b = int
    a = entry1.get()
    for a in slova:
        здесь не могу придумать
        
    #else:
       #b = mb.askyesno(
          #  title="Error",
          #  message="Ошибка")


root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')

label1 = Label(text='Введите ваше число:', width=20)
entry1 = Entry(width=20)
button1 = Button(text='Нажми сюда', command=__init__, bg="#ffccff")

label1.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
entry1.grid(row=0, column = 2)
button1.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=E)

slova = ['ноль','один','два','три','четыре','пять',
         'шесть','семь','восемь','девять','десять']
numbers = ['0','1','2','3','4','5',
           '6','7','8','9','10']
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 6):

Или обойтись без индексов, чтоб не переписывать списки, если в них что-то добавиться, тем самым увеличивая вероятность допустить ошибку, а использовать словари:

```
>>> digits = {'один': 1, 'два': 2, 'три': 3, 'стопятьсот': 100500}

>>> digits.get('один')
1

>>> digits.get('стопятьсот')
100500

>>> print(digits.get('сорок два'))
None

>>> print(digits.get('тринадцать', 'незнакомое число'))
незнакомое число
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)

Answer (score 2):

```
print(numbers[slova.index('два')])
```

Можно взять индекс искомого слова в списке слов и потом по этому индексу взять значение в списке цифр. Цикл не нужен. Вернее, можно и с циклом сделать, но смысла нет.

Со словарём хорошая мысль от Jack_oS, словарь этот можно легко сделать из имеющихся у вас списков:

```
slova_num = {s: n for s, n in zip(slova, numbers)}
print(slova_num['два'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> slova = ['ноль','один','два','три','четыре','пять',
...          'шесть','семь','восемь','девять','десять']
>>> numbers = ['0','1','2','3','4','5',
...            '6','7','8','9','10']
>>> slovar = dict(zip(numbers,slova))
>>> slovar.update(zip(slova,numbers))
>>> slovar.get('0')
'ноль'
>>> slovar.get('ноль')
'0'
>>>
```